# Type checking: an iterable type that is not a string

Tags: python, python-3.x, typechecking

To explain better, consider this simple type checker function:

```
from collections import Iterable
def typecheck(obj):
    return not isinstance(obj, str) and isinstance(obj, Iterable)
```

If `obj` is an iterable type other than `str`, it returns `True`.  However, if `obj` is a `str` or a non-iterable type, it returns `False`.

Is there any way to perform the type check more efficiently?  I mean, it seems kinda redundant to check the type of `obj` once to see if it is not a `str` and then check it *again* to see if it is iterable.

I thought about listing every other iterable type besides `str` like this:

```
return isinstance(obj, (list, tuple, dict,...))
```

But the problem is that that approach will miss any other iterable types that are not explicitly listed.

So...is there anything better or is the approach I gave in the function the most efficient?

Comment: Just curious. Why do you consider string as a non-iterable?

Comment: It's not inefficient. You likely have more important things to worry about.

Comment: @thefourtheye - Because sometimes you need to check if something is iterable but isn't a string.  An example could be a function that flattens a nested list.  You don't want the strings in it flattened as well.

Comment: @iCodez: But you want the dicts flattened? Or the files? In this specific case, it seems more reasonable to specifically check for lists. That said, there are legitimate use cases where you want to accept either a string or a sequence of strings, and you want to distinguish between the two.

Comment: Something like `return isinstance(obj, (list, tuple, dict,...))` will be far more inefficient since it has to check all the types, isn't it?

Comment: If you exclude str, usually you should exclude unicode and buffer too

Comment: TBH, I think you're already on the right track.

Comment: @aIKid - Yea, I didn't like the `isinstance(obj, (list, tuple, dict,...))` solution too much either.  I was just curious if there was any way to do this without calling `isinstance` twice.  But now I'm beginning to think that that _is_ actually the best way.

Comment: It *is*. It has to check it only twice, for each types. No solution can do it better.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In **python 2.x**, Checking for the `__iter__` attribute was helpful (though not always wise), because iterables should have this attribute, but strings did not.

```
def typecheck(obj): return hasattr(myObj, '__iter__')
```

The down side was that `__iter__` was not a truely Pythonic way to do it: Some objects might implement `__getitem__` but not `__iter__` for instance.

In **Python 3.x**, strings got the `__iter__` attribute, breaking this method.

The method you listed is the most efficient truely Pythonic way I know in Python 3.x:

```
def typecheck(obj): return not isinstance(obj, str) and isinstance(obj, Iterable)
```

There is a much faster (more efficient) way, which is to check `__iter__` like in Python 2.x, and then subsequently check `str`.

```
def typecheck(obj): return hasattr(obj, '__iter__') and not isinstance(obj, str)
```

This has the same caveat as in Python 2.x, but is much faster.

Comment: There is still the distinct problem that `isinstance(u'foo', str)` returns `False` and so you end up with the same conundrum as explicitly listing all the types which are *not* string types.  As a quick hack, I came up with checking `hasattr(thing, 'lower')` but it's obviously too obscure.

Comment: @tripleee - `isinstance(u'foo', basestring)` does the trick in Python 2.x (both `unicode` and `str` subclass `basestring`)