# One of the method from my python code fails for some unittests. How do I improve it?

Tags: python, python-unittest

I have this method called `str_to_hex` in my **common.py**

```
def str_to_hex(self, text):
    self.log.info('str_to_hex :: text=%s' % text)
    hex_string = ''
    for character in text:
        hex_string += ('%x' % ord(character)).ljust(2, '0') 
    self.log.info('str_to_hex; hex = %s' % hex_string)
    return hex_string
```

The unittesting method that I am writing is

```
def test_str_to_hex(self):
    # test 1
    self.assertEqual(self.common.str_to_hex('test'), '74657374');
    # test 2
    self.assertEqual(self.common.str_to_hex(None) , '')
    # test 3
    self.assertEqual(self.common.str_to_hex(34234), '')
    # test 4
    self.assertEqual(self.common.str_to_hex({'k': 'v'}), '')
    # test 5  
    self.assertEqual(self.common.str_to_hex([None, 5]), '')
```

So the first failures that I got say

```
# failure 1 (for test 2)
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
# failure 2 (for test 3)
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
# failure 3 (for test 4)
AssertionError: '6b' != ''
# failure 4 (for test 5)
TypeError: ord() expected string of length 1, but NoneType found
```

Ideally only text (i.e. `str` or `unicode`) should be passed to `str_to_hex`

For handling empty args as input I modified my code with

```
def str_to_hex(self, text):   
    # .. some code ..
    for character in text or '':
    # .. some code
```

So it passes the second test but still fails for the third one.

If I use [hasattr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19943654/type-checking-an-iterable-type-that-is-not-a-string)(text, '__iter__'), it will still fail for test #4 and #5.

I think the best way is to use an `Exception`. But I am open to suggestions.

Please help me out. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Adding to this..do you test for additional datatypes like say a dict or a list as inputs to the method? If yes, how to avoid taking the focus away from the main logic?

Comment: That's a great point. It will work for a `list` provided it only contains `char`. e.g. ['a', 'b', 'c']. But what about `dict` and other lists?

Comment: modified the question

Comment: Why do you want an empty string, rather than an exception? That seems like it'll just hide errors and confuse the people who work on this code after you.

Comment: @user2357112 yea it should ideally be throwing out different kinds of `Exception` in the different cases.

Comment: So what different exception should I handle besides `TypeError` and `AssertionError` in case a method is only able to process **text**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, you need to decide whether you want to (a) silently return empty strings for invalid input like lists, dicts, etc. OR (b) you actually are fine with raising appropriate exceptions, just want your tests to deal with those.

For (a), you can make your function itself more defensive about what it's getting passed:

```
def str_to_hex(self, text):
    if not isinstance(text, basestring):
        return ''
    # rest of code
```

For option (b), you can change your test expectations to match what's happening:

```
with self.assertRaises(TypeError):
    self.common.str_to_hex(None)
# etc.
```

Comment: I have seen that some texts have datatype = `unicode` (e.g. `u'á'`). Will the test fail for such text?

Comment: I just tried `self.assertEqual(self.common.str_to_hex(u'á'), '')` against option (a) and it fails with `AssertionError`

Comment: `basestring` will allow both unicode and normal strings through. IF you want to disallow unicode as well, just change it to `isinstance(text, str)`.

Comment: yes. that's correct. My test should have been `self.assertEqual(self.common.str_to_hex(u'á'), 'e1')`. Sorry :(

Comment: I don't think Option-A will work. Option-B is not really an option. Its doesnt explain what we should be doing in the main code. 
Here `basestring` does the job, but at many places it wont. Will you end up putting in `or` statements like `isinstance(x1) or isinstance(x2)` ?? Also if you do it this way, I think we are concentrating more on the test code rather than the main logic since more than half the lines of code is actually just catching exceptions and throwing them. And this is only the code which test for type (the useless part I would call) since main test logic isn't in this.

Comment: I agree with you. Maybe I should put the validations in a decorator. That way it will be separate from my actual logic. I too mixing the actual logic and the extra coating.